# User prompt is one line off for some reason?

Tags: java, input, stdin

I'm asking for user input, but I want it to follow the enter: prompt and be on the same line.

My code produces this as a result input from 'ok'

```
ok
enter: ok
ok
```

I would like the user input to start after enter: - hoping for this as a result...

```
enter: ok
ok
```

---

Here's my code:

```
private static Scanner u = new Scanner(System.in);
  try{
      while(u.hasNext() && !u.equals("exit")) {
          System.out.printf("enter: ");
          usrInput = u.next();
          System.out.printf(usrInput + "\n");
          System.out.println(findClosestMatch(usrInput.toLowerCase()));
        }
      } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Error - NullPointerException");
      }
```

Comment: `u.equals("exit")` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I was using that to not get a NULL value

Comment: Huh? What do you mean @Yawn ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`u.hasNext()` is blocking on input before the prompt. It's unnecessary, since calling `u.next()` afterwards will block anyway. And you're comparing the actual `Scanner` object to "exit", which will never be true. Try this:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("enter: ");
    if (!u.hasNext() || (usrInput = u.next()).equals("exit")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(usrInput);
    System.out.println(findClosestMatch(usrInput.toLowerCase()));
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you - But doesn't my while loop need to be able to throw an exception?

Comment: @Yawn a) Your try/catch block surrounds the loop, so it's outside the scope of my snippet. b) I'm not sure what you mean by "need[ing] to be able to throw an exception". Try/catch enables you to *catch* an exception; nothing's stopping your code from *throwing* an exception. c) I don't see where or why you're expecting an exception in the first place.

Comment: If I run the program and pipe in a text file as the usrinput - it will reach the EOF and throw a NullPointerException.  I would like to be able to catch or throw that without an error

Comment: @Yawn I'm surprised it wouldn't throw `NoSuchElementException`. But in any case, I've added back your `hasNext()` check for that case.

Comment: Just ran - yes you are right its throwing NoSuchElementException

Comment: This code always ends with NoSuchElementException from my catch block when piping in a text file.  hmm.  I can remove the System.out of the Error and it ends normally but that doesn't seem right